# How to have the proper order of .mod in makefile

Tags: makefile, fortran

I'm trying to do a Makefile for my project in Fortran and make it reusable for now projects. The Mkefile I have come up with after many tries is the following. The thing is that it works OK in few scenarios but right now I have this files:

main.f90, initial.f90, parameters.f90, functions.f90

The first one has my program and the others are modules where I have subroutines. The thing is that initial needs parameters to work but the Makefile decides to try compiling initial before parameters. Is there a way I can make it to choose them in the right order?

```
vpath %.o obj
vpath %.mod mod 

TOP_DIR = .
MOD_DIR = $(TOP_DIR)/mod
OBJ_DIR = $(TOP_DIR)/obj

SOURCES = $(wildcard *.f90)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.f90, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
ALL_MODULES = $(patsubst %.f90, %.mod, $(SOURCES))
MODULES = $(filter-out main.mod, $(ALL_MODULES))

FFLAGS = -O3 -J$(MOD_DIR) -march=native  -fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -fwhole-file  

.PHONY: main clean

main: main.out
./main.out

main.out: $(MODULES) $(OBJECTS)
gfortran $(FFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o main.out

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.f90
gfortran  $(FFLAGS) $^ -c $@

%.mod: %.f90
gfortran  $(FFLAGS) -c $^

clean:
rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o *.out $(MOD_DIR)/*.mod
```

Comment: As I have commented many times, Makefiles are competely inadequate for modern Fortran and lead to exactly these problems. Even if you fix it once, adding any new file into the project is a great pain-in-the-arse. There are many modern alternatives available: cmake, scons, fobis, waf...

Comment: If you really must use Make, you can try to parse the dependencies from the sources and tell `make` to use them. See e.g. [parser using awk](https://gitlab.com/acclab/parcas/blob/727af5e7c31c6926935c1a7fc6b66472bdca1764/resolve_dependencies.awk) and [complicated Makefile](https://gitlab.com/acclab/parcas/blob/727af5e7c31c6926935c1a7fc6b66472bdca1764/Makefile#L126).

Comment: @VladimirF you will have to *somehow* encode the dependency order in any of these tools.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Not so, these tools are able to scan the source files and determine the order automatically.

Comment: @VladimirF of course you are right, but in my meaning this is included in the "somehow", as the generation of such a tree is entirely unrelated to the rest of the functions of these tools; it is a pity that this step of the generation toolchain never got the attention it deserves. In my career I ran into countless desasters caused by half-a$$ed build tools where just *one* clean dependency tree implementation plus make would have made all the difference.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I spent a few years with make and and I never want to come back. Not only the compilation took ages because of needless recompilation, but adding a new file or even a new dependency was a royal PITA and one ended up with growing files instead.

Comment: @VladimirF needless recompilation with `make` can only happen if the underlying language(s) miss a proper (and modern) form of name management. In some cases (like C and C++) this is mitigated with the help from the compiler. But I can see your frustration as I am also of the opinion that `make` should be retired - just not in exchange for things like cmake (which needs make anyway, no?) or scons.

Comment: One solution would be to reorganize your project, with another level of subdirectories to treat more easily dependencies problems like that. If your directory tree is based on your dependency tree, you'll avoid lots of trouble with Make.

Answer (score 0):

List the source files in the dependency order instead of automatically: `SOURCES = parameters.f90 initial.f90 functions.f90`.

Separate the source for the modules and for the program: `main.f90` does not, in general, generate `.mod` files and that will break the simplistic Makefile you have.

I also advise to use another build system (cmake, for instance) but for small projects you can get by with a Makefile if you prefer to.

Answer (score 0):

With modern Fortran compilation order is very important. When using makefiles, for anything non-trivial it's too tedious to keep track of the dependencies manually. Enter various tools to generate these dependency lists. I have successfully used `makedepf90` which is available as a package in EPEL (for RHEL/CentOS) and Debian/Ubuntu.

You can even make a makefile rule for regenerating the dependency list, if you keep the list in a separate file, like:

```
include depend.mk

# Dependencies generated by "makedepf90" tool.
depend depend.mk:
        cd $(srcdir) && makedepf90 $(yourprogramname_SOURCES) >depend.mk
```

The above BTW works both with plain makefiles and automake (in which case you put the above snippet to your Makefile.am)