# Trouble compiling and linking Fortran90 sources at different locations

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, compilation, fortran, gfortran

I have a directory structure like this:

```
main/
    foo.f90
    bar.f90
    main/stuff
        floop.f90
```

`foo.f90` contains a `PROGRAM` which includes functionality of `bar.f90` via the `USE` keyword, and `bar.f90` includes functionality of `floop.f90` via `USE`

My Makefile looks like:

```
# define objects, mods
objects: foo.o bar.o floop.o
mods: foo.mod bar.mod floop.mod
FC = gfortran

# make
foo: $(objects)
    $(FC) -o foo $(objects)
floop.o : stuff/floop.f90
    $(FC) -c stuff/floop.f90
bar.o : bar.f90
    $(FC) -c bar.f90
foo.o : bar.o floop.o foo.f90
    $(FC) -c foo.f90
```

Trying to `make` this, though, I get an error from the `bar.f90` source:

```
gfortran -c bar.f90

use floop                         
    1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'floop.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

How do I make gfortran aware of the location of thus module? As I understand, `mod` files are created in the current working directory by default, so I thought that constructing the `floop.o` target correctly, by explicitly pointing to the source at `stuff/floop.f90`, would be sufficient.

Comment: Have you compiled the `floop` module source by the time you try to compile other things using that module? Your makefile snippet doesn't suggest correct decency order

Comment: @francescalus it may be that the line `$(FC) -c stuff/floop.f90` is silently failing, though I don't know what that would be

Comment: If you delete all built objects, then what does `make -n` say? `objects: foo.o bar.o floop.o` means one expects `bar.f90` to be compiled before `stuff/floop.f90`.

Comment: @francescalus ah, this may have fixed it... I thought the instructions to make each target just needed to be in order (i.e. the calls to gfortran), but didn't know the list of objects needed to be ordered as well

Comment: @francescalus it now seems that everything works up to the last instruction to compile `foo`, when I see that every variables from `bar.f90` that I try to access gives `undefined reference to `__bar_MOD_variable'`

Comment: The order of the recipes in the makefile is generally insignificant when it comes to order of actions. Order of dependencies matters more: see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56576406/3157076).

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66855252/3157076) is a good starting point for undefined reference errors. If that doesn't help, please [edit] more detail to your question (with [mre] ideally).